# Want to update a Campaign field if Lead is created or updated

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, campaign, campaign-member

I created 2 custom fields on Campaign and I want those fields to be updated if the **Moved to MQL** or **Moved to SQL** fields (these are checkbox fields on Lead) are checked. The two custom fields are **Number of SQLs** & **Number of MQLs**. My code is as below:

```
trigger Lead_MQLSQL on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    Double noOfMQL = 0;
    Double noOfSQL = 0;
    Set<ID> CampaignIDs= new Set<ID>();

    List<CampaignMember> cms = [SELECT CampaignID, LeadID, Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadID IN : Trigger.new];
    List<Lead> leads = [SELECT ID, Status, Moved_to_SQL__c, moved_to_MQL__c FROM Lead WHERE ID IN : Trigger.new];

    for (CampaignMember cm : cms) {
        if(CampaignIDs.contains(cm.CampaignID) == FALSE) {
            CampaignIDs.add(cm.CampaignID);
        }
    }

    List<CampaignMember> campaigns = [SELECT id FROM CampaignMember WHERE id IN: CampaignIDs];

    for (Lead lead : leads) {
        if(lead.Moved_to_SQL__c == true) {
            noOfMQL++;
        } else if (lead.moved_to_MQL__c == true) {
            noOfSQL++;
        }
    }

    for(CampaignMember c : campaigns) {
        c.Campaign.SQL_Generated_del__c = noOfMQL;
        c.Campaign.SQL_Generated_del__c = noOfSQL;
    }

    update campaigns;
}
```

I have done this and I can't see its effect or any errors.

Comment: I've added a possible solution to your problem.  I've tried to provide as much comments as possible to make it understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update an object through a relationship.  This bit of code isn't going to do anything.

```
for(CampaignMember c : campaigns) {
    c.Campaign.SQL_Generated_del__c = noOfMQL;
    c.Campaign.SQL_Generated_del__c = noOfSQL;
}
```

What you could do is either query the Campaign object, populate the fields directly, and update the list of Campaign objects.  Or you could instantiate the Campaign objects in memory, assign the Id field along with the other fields and update those. This method allows you to avoid an extra SOQL query.

That being said your trigger has a number of issues and inefficiencies.

This SOQL query is unnecessary, you have all the needed information in Trigger.new

```
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT ID, Status, Moved_to_SQL__c, moved_to_MQL__c FROM Lead WHERE ID IN : Trigger.new];
```

You could just do this

```
List<Lead> leads = Trigger.new;
```

In this block of code checking to see if the Id is already added is unnecessary.  Sets automatically restrict themselves to unique values.

```
for (CampaignMember cm : cms) {
    //if(CampaignIDs.contains(cm.CampaignID) == FALSE) {
        CampaignIDs.add(cm.CampaignID);
    //}
}
```

In this block of code `noOfSQL` will not increment if `noOfMQL` does.  If/Esle means one or the other.

```
for (Lead lead : leads) {
    if(lead.Moved_to_SQL__c == true) {
        noOfMQL++;
    } else if (lead.moved_to_MQL__c == true) {
        noOfSQL++;
    }
}
```

It seems like you would want two If statements

```
for (Lead lead : leads) {
    if(lead.Moved_to_SQL__c == true) {
        noOfMQL++;
    }
    if(lead.moved_to_MQL__c == true) {
        noOfSQL++;
    }
}
```

Also you need to consider that counting records in the manner you are currently attempting will not get an accurate count by Campaign.  Instead it will get the total amount for ALL leads and add them to ALL Campaign records.

Below is one possible solution.  The SOQL is a bit complex and I tried to comment it as much as possible to make it understandable.  Note this solution is more brute force.  It will recalculate the entire set of Leads per Campaign when just one changes.  Monitor it well, if you have very large data sets that are affected by this, you may need to consider ways to make it more streamlined.

```
// Set to store Ids of Leads whose field value(s) have changed
Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
// Compare old record versus updated record.
// This filter's out any records whos value
// did not change.
for(Lead newLead : Trigger.new)
{
    Lead oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(newLead.Id);
    // Check to see if field has changed
    if( newLead.Moved_to_SQL__c != oldLead.Moved_to_SQL__c )
    {
        leadIds.add(newLead.Id);
    }
    // Check to see if field has changed
    if( newLead.Moved_to_MQL__c != oldLead.Moved_to_SQL__c )
    {
        leadIds.add(newLead.Id);
    }
}

// Query using Campaign with a Subquery on CampaignMembers
// filtering on the Lead records we want to count.
// This way you can get an accurate number of
// Lead records per Campaign
List<Campaign> campaigns = [SELECT Id, Number_of_SQLs__c, Number_of_MQLs__c, SQL_Generated_del__c
                                // Subquery on CampaignMember. Utilize relationship to get Lead Field
                                // Filter / return only CampaignMember records with the Lead fields checked
                                (SELECT Lead.Moved_to_SQL__c, Lead.Moved_to_MQL__c FROM CampaignMembers WHERE Lead.Moved_to_SQL__c = true OR Lead.Moved_to_MQL__c = true)
                            FROM Campaign
                            // Filter Campaigns based on CampaignMembers records based on Trigger.new Leads
                            WHERE Id IN (SELECT CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadId IN leadIds)];

// Loop through all Campaign records returned.
for(Campaign camp : campaigns)
{
    // Reset numbers per Campaign
    Integer numSQL = 0;
    Integer numMQL = 0;
    // Utilize child relationship and loop through all CampaignMembers
    for(CampaignMember member : camp.CampaignMembers)
    {
        // Increment MQL
        if(member.Lead.Moved_to_MQL__c)
        {
            numMQL++;
        }
        // Increment SQL
        if(member.Lead.Moved_to_SQL__c)
        {
            numSQL++;
        }
    }
    // Assign SQL/MQL totals to respective fields on Campaign
    c.Number_of_SQLs__c = numSQL;
    c.Number_of_MQLs__c = numMQL;
    // This was in your example, best I can figure is you
    // wanted a total, if I'm wrong just remove/delete
    c.SQL_Generated_del__c = numSQL + numMQL;
}

// Update Campaigns
update campaigns;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all lowpoint. It would be good, if you can proffer more towards the solution - I'm new to this. @DougB

Comment: `for(CampaignMember member : campaigns.CampaignMember)
        {
            // Increment MQL
            if(member.Lead.Moved_to_MQL__c)
            {
                numMQL++;
            }
            // Increment SQL
            if(member.Lead.Moved_to_SQL__c)
            {
                numSQL++;
            }
        }`
it threw concerning the for loop. **Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Campaign>** @DougB

Comment: @DIPXOID sorry, I made a typo in the for loop.  I fixed the typo in my answer.

Comment: I should have spotted that. _Facepalm_